# How to get css styles like width in Angular using ElementRef and Renderer and having compatibility with ng Universal?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hei, this is the situation.

In the template I have:

```
<div class="deslizador" #deslizador>
```

And in the component:

```
@ViewChild('deslizador') deslizador : ElementRef;
```

And after some calculation and click events I modify the left css property this way:

```
this.deslizador.nativeElement.style.left=this.leftpx+'%';
```

Yes, this is a slider. Is this touching the DOM and because of this Angular Universal (or webworker, etc..) will have a problem here? I think I'm modifying some css style here and reading it through nativeElement but I don't know if this is touching the DOM = not angular universal compatible.

IS there a better way to read a css property and modify it with Renderer?

Also, is there any way to read a css property different or more angular universal compatible or elegant than..?

`window.getComputedStyle(this.element.nativeElement).minWidth`

Thanks